# Redirect port and ip on macOS

Tags: macos, ip, iptables, macos-sierra

I'm working on a mac with OS 10.13.6.

I want to redirect all requests to 10.20.154.24:1111 made from my computer go to localhost:8080.

I read about pf and pfctl, but could not make this work.

I thought to run this, but it didn't work...

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 to 10.20.154.24 port 1111 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution. I had to make an alias out of the IP before setting the redirecting command

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 10.20.154.24 alias
```